# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 4: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, character-encoding

I exported a csv file from Microsoft Excel. It showed properly in Jupyter notebook with pandas and numpy as below:

```
import pandas as pd
pd1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

There were no error messages the first time, but I just opened the csv file then just saved as a new name.

all the time I got  a unicodeerror message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

The data has strange letters as shown below. Even if there were strange letters, there was no problem at first.

2 columns, 6 rows

[image: data]

I have to handle all languages, so I really want to know how to encode them. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you use Excel to save the file with a new name? Apparently, a different encoding was used for saving (not UTF-8 anymore). Maybe you can repeat the steps for "save as" and look out for an option concerning encoding. Then make sure you choose UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

When you save as, there will be a selection of the encoding format

[image: How to select]

Try to save as and see if it works.